# Bigquery timestamp_diff

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to calculate the difference between two timestamp type columns which I do with timestamp_diff:

```sql
select timestamp_diff('2023-01-01 17:00:00 UTC','2023-01-01 15:10:00 UTC', minute)
```

but I would like the result to be as follows:

`01:50`

any ideas?

*** UPDATE ***

@SelVazi solution is ok, but when I have in columns different days, its calculate wrong. ie:

DIFF IN SAME DAY:

```sql
select timestamp_diff('2023-01-01 17:00:00 UTC','2023-01-01 15:10:00 UTC', minute)
```

the result is ok: 01:50

DIFFERENT DAYS:

```sql
select timestamp_diff('2023-01-03 17:00:00 UTC','2023-01-01 15:10:00 UTC', minute)
```

it's same result: 01:50

How fix it? I'm newbie in sql

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`TIME_ADD`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#time_add) :

```
SELECT TIME_ADD(
         TIME '0:0:0',
         INTERVAL TIMESTAMP_DIFF('2023-01-01 17:00:00 UTC','2023-01-01 15:10:00 UTC', MINUTE) MINUTE
       ) AS time_difference  ;
```

If you want time in the format **hh:mm** :

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIME("%R", 
         TIME_ADD(
           TIME '0:0:0',
           INTERVAL TIMESTAMP_DIFF('2023-01-01 17:00:00 UTC','2023-01-01 15:11:00 UTC', MINUTE) MINUTE
         )
       ) AS time_difference;
```

Comment: thanks @selvazi for your answers! One question: What if the date between columns is different?

Comment: I didn’t get it ! Can you share more details/exemple?

Comment: Following the example:
`select timestamp_diff('2023-01-03 17:00:00 UTC','2023-01-01 15:10:00 UTC', minute)` when one date is +1 day...

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us what do you want as result in this case ?